# Is there a way to Implement Quicksort without Loops or Helper Functions (Only Recursion)?

Tags: python, recursion, quicksort

Is there a way to implement quicksort without any loops at all and without helper functions like the partition function?

Here is my code:

```
def quicksort(lst):

    if len(lst) <= 1:
        return lst

    pivot = lst[0]

    items_greater_than_pivot = []
    items_equal_to_pivot = []
    items_less_than_pivot = []

    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[i] < pivot:
            items_less_than_pivot.append(lst[i])
        elif lst[i] == pivot:
            items_equal_to_pivot.append(lst[i])
        else:
            items_greater_than_pivot.append(lst[i])
            
    return quicksort(items_less_than_pivot) + quicksort(items_equal_to_pivot) + 
    quicksort(items_greater_than_pivot)
```

I want to do this algorithm without using any for/while loops and without the use of a helper function (like partition) in the in-place way.

I only want to do recursion here.

Any ideas on how this is possible?

Comment: Yes... this is possible... by replacing loops with recursion? What exactly is unclear to you about this?

Comment: You are already using recursion, actually.

Comment: Nothing is unclear. I am just hoping to not use any loops or helper functions and only use recursion to do the algorithm. But I can't think of a way to achieve this without a loop like here. I need some hints

Comment: I know I am using recursion. But is there a way to not use any loops at all in this algorithm?

Comment: You can always replace loops with recursion. I don't know how you would do that in this case without using a helper function. But I'm inclined to say it's possible.